# Cannot fire the event of a hyperlink using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working with MVC3 technology with AJAX and jQuery in ASP.Net.

As per my requirements I have created a table dynamically. There is a hyperlink along with the each last `td` of each `tr`, like: `<a href = "#">edit</a>`.

I have encapsulated the code of generating the table within a user defined function, but the problem is that whenever I want to generate the click event of the hyperlink using jQuery from outside the function, the table is not being recognized by the page. Naturally it can't recognize the children of the table as well as the attribute, like the hyperlink, so I cannot fire the click event of the hyperlink.

Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: could you provide us with some code, or even better a fiddle?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have. Your question doesn't make a great deal of sense as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that the problem you're facing is that the events aren't being bound to dynamically-generated elements (since they're not present in the DOM at the point of event-binding). To deal with this, use `on()`, and pass a selector to identify the element-type upon which you want to handle events:

```
$(selector).on('click', 'table a', function(e){
    // do stuff here when a link inside a table is clicked
});
```

Or you could use `delegate()` instead (in versions of jQuery lower than 1.7):

```
$(selector).delegate('table a', 'click', function(e){
    // do stuff here when a link inside a table is clicked
});
```

References:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).